# How to use \ in a string in python

Tags: python, string, printing, backslash

When I try to use

```
    print variable + "\filename"
```

the slash isn't recognized as a string character,
however if I were to do

```
    print variable + "\Filename"
```

capitalizing the first letter proceeding the slash... then the slash is recognized as a string character

The only thing I was able to find online is that in some cases a \ with a letter preceding it may be used to end a string of raw characters but I don't understand this.

So my question is why does this happen? And more importantly what is a way around this or a fix for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark it as raw with the prefix `r`. Like this: `print variable + r"\filename"` Or alternatively you can escape it using a backslash `print variable + "\\filename"`